# Google Load Balancer firewall for instances/backends under LB

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a load balancer with 3 different backends with 3 different “host and path rules”. So depending on the url the LB will redirect to 3 different backends. Each backend is connected to an instance group (3 different groups) and each group only contains 1 single instance (a total of 3 different instances).

Is it possible to apply firewall rules for specific backends? So that for 1 of the backends make a firewall rule so that it is only accessible from my IP address.

Or is this something I have to handle in my servers and block/allow the specific IP’s I want to have access to the servers.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Navigate to your firewall rules and create separate rules for each backend. The prerequisite for that would be having a tag applied to each instance in each group, for example tag `green` to each instance in instance group green and tag `blue` to each instance in instance group blue.

Here how this should look like (of course your settings may vary)

[image]

Comment: Again, thank you so much. Unfortunately I am not able to test this until Monday. However, doing it this way, I would also need to add my LB ip to that source IP to allow it, right? And doing it that way, would not all connections to my lb, which redirect to this instance also be allowed?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this seems to be an L7/HTTP(S) balancer. In that case, the source IP range will be [130.211.0.0/22](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#troubleshooting)

Comment: @mensi Yes, it is a HTTP Load Balancer. If the source IP is always in that range, does that not mean it is impossible to have different firewall rules for separate backends under the same LB?

Comment: @Yon yes, you'll have to do HTTP-level access restrictions. If you insist on using the IP, you could look at `X-Forwarded-For` instead

Comment: @mensi Thank you! I also found the X-Forwarded-For header yesterday so I started implementing it. I can't except you comment but if you were to write an answer saying that it's not possible to have separate firewall rules for each backend as I asked in my question I can accept that! :)